# Embed Protected Dash Webapp/Webpage in Other Authenticated HTML webpage using <iFrame>

Tags: html, python-3.x, iframe, plotly-dash, dashboard

Could you please explain or provide the solution for how to embed the Authentication Enabled (Protected) Dash Webpage in another authentication needing HTML page using  ?

python dash plotly html webapp webpage dashboard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: here is what documentation says - https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash